# Checking for date range conflicts with Access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I'm having trouble writing a query that will tell me if a given car is booked for a specified date period. My table is called `Bookings` and has `CarID`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns. I want to return a row if the car is booked for the period that the user enters. At the moment I have this query, which I got from the internet and some tinkering:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bookings
WHERE BookingID NOT IN
(SELECT BookingID
 FROM Bookings
 WHERE
   (StartDate <= user_start_date AND EndDate >= user_start_date) OR
   (StartDate <= user_end_date AND EndDate >= user_end_date) OR
   (StartDate >= user_start_date AND EndDate <= user_end_date)) AND
   (CarID = 7)
```

Here, I'm using `user_start_date` as my start date from the user and `user_end_date` as the end date from the user, and `7` for the car. However, the logic doesn't seem to work. Even when I verify there's absolutely no clashes in the dates it always returns rows.

How can I ammend this query so it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that none of the dates can be null, and the start dates are less than the end dates, the following query should list any bookings for car 7 that overlap the given date range:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bookings
WHERE CarID = 7
AND StartDate < user_end_date
AND EndDate > user_start_date
```